# Why am I getting these errors?

Tags: java, find, symbols, inventory

```
// Inventory.java part 1
// this program is to calculate the value of the inventory of the Electronics Department's cameras

import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Inventory
{
public void main(String[] args)
{
   // create Scanner to obtain input from the command window
   Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

   int itemNumber; // first number to multiply
   int itemStock; // second number to multiply
   double itemPrice; //
   double totalValue; // product of number1 and number2



while(true){   // infinite loop
           // make new Camera object
Cam camera = new Cam(name, itemNumber, itemStock, itemPrice, totalValue);

   System.out.print("Enter Department name: "); //prompt
   String itemDept = input.nextLine(); // read name from user

    if(itemDept.equals("stop"))  // exit the loop
        break;


   while(true){
   System.out.print("Enter item name: "); // prompt
   String name = input.nextLine(); // read first number from user
   input.nextLine();
      if(name != ("camera"))
         System.out.print("Enter valid item name:"); // prompt
         name = input.nextLine(); // read first number from user
         input.nextLine();
      break;


   }

   System.out.print("Enter number of items on hand: "); // prompt
   itemStock = input.nextInt(); // read first number from user
   input.nextLine();
      while( itemStock <= -1){
         System.out.print("Enter positive number of items on hand:"); // prompt
         itemStock = input.nextInt(); // read first number from user
         input.nextLine();
         } /* while statement with the condition that negative numbers are entered
         user is prompted to enter a positive number */

   System.out.print("Enter item Price: "); // prompt
   itemPrice = input.nextDouble(); // read second number from user
   input.nextLine();
      while( itemPrice <= -1){
        System.out.print("Enter positive number for item price:"); // prompt
        itemPrice = input.nextDouble(); // read first number from user
        input.nextLine();
         } /* while statement with the condition that negative numbers are entered
         user is prompted to enter a positive number */




   totalValue = itemStock * itemPrice; // multiply numbers

   System.out.println("Department name:" + itemDept); // display Department name
   System.out.println("Item number: " + camera.getItemNumber()); //display Item number
   System.out.println("Product name:" + camera.getName()); // display the item
   System.out.println("Quantity: " + camera.getItemStock());
   System.out.println("Price per unit" + camera.getItemPrice());
   System.out.printf("Total value is: $%.2f\n", camera.getTotalValue()); // display product

   } // end while method

} // end method main

}/* end class Inventory */

class Cam{

   private String name;
   private int itemNumber;
   private int itemStock;
   private double itemPrice;
   private String deptName;

   private Cam(String name, int itemNumber, int itemStock, double itemPrice, double totalValue) {
  this.name = name;
  this.itemNumber = itemNumber;
  this.itemStock = itemStock;
  this.itemPrice = itemPrice;
  this.totalValue = totalValue;
 }

 public String getName(){
  return name;
  }


 public double getTotalValue(){
  return itemStock * itemPrice;
  }

  public int getItemNumber(){
  return itemNumber;

  }

  public int getItemStock(){
  return itemStock;

  }

  public double getItemPrice(){
  return itemPrice;

  }

  }
```

This is the output when I try to compile this code:

```
  C:\Java>javac Inventory.java
    Inventory.java:25: error: cannot find symbol
    Cam camera = new Cam(name, itemNumber, itemStock, itemPrice, totalValue);
                         ^
symbol:   variable name
location: class Inventory
Inventory.java:98: error: cannot find symbol
      this.totalValue = totalValue;
          ^
 symbol: variable totalValue
2 errors
```

I don't understand why I keep getting these errors. I feel like I am close to finishing the problem, but find that I need help getting over this bit of the problem.

Okay, I have made a few changes, but now I get these errors:

```
    C:\Java>javac Inventory.java
    Inventory.java:68: error: variable itemNumber might not have been initialized
    Cam camera = new Cam(name, itemNumber, itemStock, itemPrice, totalValue);

                                  ^
    Inventory.java:68: error: variable totalValue might not have been initialized
    Cam camera = new Cam(name, itemNumber, itemStock, itemPrice, totalValue);
                                                                    ^
    2 errors
```

Comment: Please check the opening and closing curly braces { .. }

Comment: Its clearly saying `itemNumber` and  `totalValue ` might not be initialized ! why dont you initialize these variables ? Guess you have to initialize `itemPrice` and  `totalValue` as well..

Answer (score 1):

You have declared a variable *totalValue* inside the main function of the *Inventory* class. It is not available for class *Cam* as an instance (*this*) variable.

Answer (score 1):

Your missing declaration for the variable `name` in main.

```
// create Scanner to obtain input from the command window
Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

String name; //missing declaration
int itemNumber; // first number to multiply
int itemStock; // second number to multiply
double itemPrice; //
double totalValue; // product of number1 and number2
```

Also:

```
class Cam{

    private String name;
    private int itemNumber;
    private int itemStock;
    private double itemPrice;
    private String deptName;
    private double totalValue; //missing field

    private Cam(String name, int itemNumber, int itemStock, double itemPrice, double totalValue) {
```

The constructor is private.

Your are also missing `static` in your main method.

Answer (score 1):

The two errors are pretty simple:

First:

> ```
> Inventory.java:25: error: cannot find symbol
> Cam camera = new Cam(name, itemNumber, itemStock, itemPrice, totalValue);
>                      ^
> symbol:   variable name
> location: class Inventory
> ```

This sais it cannot find the variable called `name`, which is true. There is no name variable in the scope when you try to construct the `Cam`. We know you have a `name` variable a bit further, but that does not work, because the variable isn't in the scope of the `new`statement.

Second:

> ```
> Inventory.java:98: error: cannot find symbol
>       this.totalValue = totalValue;
>            ^
>  symbol: variable totalValue
> ```

It sais it can't find a value called `totalValue` in the `Cam` class, which is true as well. Check out the member list of `Cam` and you will see that there is no `totalValue`. I guess you want to remove it from the constructor, because you are calculating total value depending on `itemStock` and `itemPrice`.

Notes:
If you solved this, (and probably more compilation errors) you will notice that your application will compile, but not run. This is because of you forget to declare your `main`-method `static`.

If you have solved this you will notice that all the `Cam` objects you constructed, will contain the data you entered for the previous `Cam`. This is because of you are constructing the `Cam` before prompting the data. You started good: Declare fields for the data you want to prompt. When the user entered all the data of **one** Camera, construct the `Camera`.

Comment: so how exactly would I fix the first error. I know you say it is simple, but I cannot seem to get it to work. I have tried moving the placement of the line of code, but have not been able to figure out where I should place the code

Comment: There has to be a variable called `name` before you try to construct the cam.

Answer (score 0):

There are two classes in your file

1. Inventory
2. Cam

You need to define

1. variable `name` in Class Inventory
2. variable `totalValue` in Class Cam

Also your in Inventory.java the call to `Cam` constructor seems to be at a wrong place, you might want to make it the last line of `While` loop